# "Reach outside" meaning

Tags: meaning

What does "reach outside" mean? for example:

> I admire the impulse to reach outside familiar cultural traditions in order seek wisdom
>   <sub>[America’s fascination with the quasi-mystical aura of Marie Kondo is another misuse of Eastern ideas](https://www.alternet.org/2019/02/americas-fascination-with-the-quasi-mystical-aura-of-marie-kondo-is-another-misuse-of-eastern-ideas/)</sub>

Comment: When you quote someone else's words, you **must** give attribution to them. I have done this for you here, but you need to do this for yourself in the future. Please see the rules [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To go beyond, to think outside of the box, to consider alternatives.

"I admire the impulse to extend one's research beyond familiar cultural traditions in order to seek wisdom."